# How to use Ruby's CSV.parse to insert all columns of data into SQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, csv

I'm having trouble with parsing my ICD Code CSV file. The 'descriptions' are saving correctly, but the codes are not being inserted alongside them. I've tried multiple ways to process the file, and I cannot get both columns and all of their rows into their respective database entries. My code is below.

Seeds.rb

```
require 'csv'

icd_codes = File.read(Rails.root.join('lib', 'seeds', 'icd10cm_order_2017.csv'))
icd_codes = CSV.parse(icd_codes, :headers => true, :encoding => 'ISO-8859-1')

icd_codes.each do |row|
  t = Icd.new
  t.code = row['Code']
  t.description = row['Description']
  t.save
  puts "#{t.code}, #{t.description} saved"
end
```

Schema.rb

```
create_table "icds", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "code"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end
```

My CSV File

```
Code    Description
A00     Cholera
A000    Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar cholerae
A001    Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar eltor
A009    Cholera, unspecified
A01     Typhoid and paratyphoid fevers
A010    Typhoid fever
```

Rails Console output

```
[#<Icd id: 1, code: nil, description: "Cholera", created_at: "2017-01-04 19:18:31", updated_at: "2017-01-04 19:18:31">
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I used the position of the row in the array, instead of the header name

```
require 'csv'

icd_codes = File.read(Rails.root.join('lib', 'seeds', 'icd10cm_order_2017.csv'))
icd_codes = CSV.parse(icd_codes, :headers => true, :encoding => 'ISO-8859-1')
icd_codes.each do |row|
  t = Icd.new
  t.code = row[0]
  t.description = row[1]
  t.save!
  puts "#{t.code}, #{t.description} saved"
end
```